# Running java project in command prompt

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, command-prompt

I've created a java project in Netbeans and I am trying to run it in the command prompt by creating a .jar of the project and then doing java -jar nameOfThePorject.jar but I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/coti/tools/Rutas
        at controller.Controller.compruebaBinario(Controller.java:41)
        at view.Vista.comienzaLaFiesta(Vista.java:23)
        at musicfy.Main.main(Main.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.coti.tools.Rutas
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
        ... 3 more
```

How can I fix it? 
PS: I am running the project in Netbeans without any error

Comment: Have you combined the imports into the ,jar file? The issue seems to be finding one of your imports.

Comment: I'm cleanning and bulding the project before, dont know if thats what you mean

Comment: Please can you watch a tutorial online on how to properly compile everything into a .jar file in netbeans as this may help you further understand what is giving you the issue.